# Angular 2 - Add validator after control initialization

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I am wondering how I can add an validator to already created formControl (that was created with it own Validators). But, let's imagine that after some delay I want to add another one (or I have a custom control that contains a few validators itself) and I want to create outer Reactive form and add inner validators to outer.

Is it possible? I didn't found any information (only about re-setting all validators)
Thanks for any help!

```
  this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      testField: [{value: '', disabled: false}, [<any>Validators.required]]
    })

<form [formGroup]="testForm" novalidate>
  <custom_input>
    formControlName="testField"
    [outerFormControl]="testForm.controls.testField"
    </custom_input>


</form>
```

and after that I want to add other validator inside my custom controls. How I can do that?

custom_coontrol.ts

```
this.outerFormControl.push(Validators.maxLength(10));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <form [formGroup]="testForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" formControlName="age">
   </form>
   <button (click)="addValidation()">Add validation</button>

   {{ testForm.valid | json }}
  `,
})
export class App {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
     this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      age: [null, Validators.required]
    })
  }

  addValidation() {
    this.testForm.get('age').setValidators(Validators.maxLength(2));
  }
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qKVlPjnHjR3eD8WMwt7Z?p=preview)

Comment: Cool. It works. Thank you Patrick!  But how it possible? I read that using SetValidators will override previous validatords. NG2 API:  **Sets the synchronous validators that are active on this control. Calling this will overwrite any existing sync validators.**

Comment: I guess they changed that or something

Comment: Okay, I checked the source code and this method will add new validators to exist validators in case when passed validators will be in array. In other case it will override previous validators.
Here is the source: **function coerceToValidator(validator: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]): ValidatorFn {
  return Array.isArray(validator) ? composeValidators(validator) : validator;
}**

Comment: In case this helps someone else: This alone doesn't work in Angular 6. I needed to add `this.testForm.get('age').updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false});` after setting the validators.

Comment: If it's needed to assign a validation function dynamically (not only while form control initialization), built-in Angular Form method setValidators() is good idea to use.