# Angular2 validate form only on certain conditions

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to vlidate a user form only during create but not update

This is my validation logic

```
    this.userform = this._formbuilder.group({
  first_name: ['', Validators.required],
  last_name: ['', Validators.required],
  username: ['', Validators.compose(
    [
      Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)
    ]
  )],
  password: ['',Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,ValidationService.passwordValidator
  ])],
  email: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,ValidationService.emailValidator
  ])],
  role: ['', Validators.required],

})
```

I would like to validate the password only during create that is when the newuser variable is true so ive tried

```
    this.userform = this._formbuilder.group({
  .....

  password: ['',

       (this.newUser) ?Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,ValidationService.passwordValidator
          ]):"" 

       ],
....
})
```

The above fails an returns an error

```
rror: Error in ./UsersComponent class UsersComponent - inline  
    template:113:51 caused by: 
   v is not a function
   Error: Error in ./UsersComponent class UsersComponent -
     inline template:113:51 caused by: v is not a function
```

Comment: where is this.newUser set?

Comment: try to pass `null` instead of `""` : `this.newUser ? Validators.compose(...) : null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom validator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation) where you programmatically check for  required and call `passwordValidator` if `this.user`is available set it as the only validator.

Or

You could initially set:

```
  this.userform = this._formbuilder.group({
  .....

  password: [''] //no initial validators,
....
})
```

and in the function where `this.newUser` is set to `true`,use [setControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#setControl-anchor)

```
this.userform.setControl("password",new FormControl('',Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,ValidationService.passwordValidator
          ]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to validate the form when a user what to change his profile? That means that a user can, after an update of his profile, have no username, no password and no email? It's not logic.

Comment: This form is used in a users tale crud operation, When creating a user a default password is used, but an admin when updating user credentials he can update the password or fail to update it, Password hence is ot mandatory during update but mandatory during create.... Hope it makes sense

Comment: It makes sense! In that case, check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404485/angular-2-add-validator-after-control-initialization